# How to check if array is null or empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to check if my array is empty or null, and on base of which I want to create a condition for example.

```
if(array ==  EMPTY){
//do something
}
```

I hope I'm clear what I am asking, just need to check if my array is empty?

regards

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
if (!array || !array.count){
  ...
}
```

That checks if array is not nil, and if not - check if it is not empty.

Comment: It works but it's not completely flawless: `array.count` should be `[array count]` since you're not dealing with a property (var) here.

Comment: Nope -- `array.count` is just fine in that context.  Syntactically, anyway.  Stylistically?  No particular standard is recommended at this time.

Comment: this is the same as `if (!array.count)`

Comment: I think the weight of stylistic opinion is against dot notation for calling generic methods on an object, so I'm with @Rengers on this one. <cowers in a corner waiting for holy war>

Comment: For the sake of accuracy @Rengers and @davidf2281, NSArray.h declares count as a property `@property (readonly) NSUInteger count;`

Comment: For those, !array.count----> is giving this error-[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, try @Sachin's  array == (id)[NSNull null]

Answer (score 29):

```
if ([array count] == 0)
```

If the array is nil, it will be 0 as well, as nil maps to 0; therefore checking whether the array exists is unnecessary.

Also, you shouldn't use array.count as some suggested. It may -work-, but it's not a property, and will drive anyone who reads your code nuts if they know the difference between a property and a method.

UPDATE: Yes, I'm aware that years later, count is now officially a property.

Answer (score 12):

you can try like this

```
if ([array count] == 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to be really verbose :)

```
if (array == nil || array.count == 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

Best performance.

```
if (array.firstObject == nil)
{
    // The array is empty
}
```

The way to go with big arrays.

Comment: best answer. the others suggest to use `count` property, which implies enumerating the array and can be a performance issue with big arrays

Comment: I prefer this way as well, because we don't actually care about the exact count when we just want to check whether array is empty.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (array == (id)[NSNull null] || [array count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"array is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

As in latest version of swift 3 the ability to compare optionals with > and < is not avaliable

It is still possible to compare optionals with ==, so the best way to check if an optional array contains values is:

```
if array?.isEmpty == false {
    print("There are objects!")
}
```

as per array count

```
if array?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
    print("There are objects!")
}
```

There are other ways also and can be checked here
[link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588964/check-if-optional-array-is-empty)

Answer (score 2):

As nil maps to 0, which equals `NO`, the most elegant way should be

```
if (![array count])
```

the '==' operator is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this kind of test using 
if (nrow>0).
If your data object is not formally an array, it may work better.

Answer (score 1):

null and empty are not the same things , i suggest you treat them in differently

```
if (array == [NSNull null]) {
    NSLog(@"It's null");
} else if (array == nil || [array count] == 0) {
     NSLog(@"It's empty");
}
```

Comment: Could you please brief the difference between both the conditions, in what case which one would call?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array == nil || array.count == 0 || [array isEqaul [NSNull Null]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4**

```
if (array.isEmpty) {
    print("Array is empty")
}
else{
    print("Array is not empty")
}
```