# Is checking nil and empty for a set at the same time safe in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, null

I just want to check whether a set is empty or nil, so I wonder whether the code below is safe or not. (Would it be passible if the newValue is nil and the system runs (newValue!).count and causes an error?)

```
if newValue == nil ||  (newValue!).count == 0{
    // Actions here        
}
```

Comment: Yes it is safe because of short circuiting.  Here is a similar question on arrays:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27588964/1630618

Comment: @vacawama Thanks! I wonder if all the languages obey this kind of rule, since I know it's safe in Java.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html): *"Like the Logical AND operator above, the Logical OR operator uses short-circuit evaluation to consider its expressions. If the left side of a Logical OR expression is true, the right side is not evaluated, because it cannot change the outcome of the overall expression."*

Comment: I wouldn't generalise whether all have that possibility. Objective-C has, Swift also not sure about others

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation is quite common in languages.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: If you find yourself doing this often, you have probably used an Optional Set when you should have just used a Set. If nil and empty are the same, there's no need for an Optional at all. (If you do need this pattern, then @DepartamentoB's answer is ideal.)

Comment: @RobNapier Sounds reasonable. I will pay attention to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly safe as it will execute the second statement only when the first one is true.

It's better to use:

```
   guard let newValue = newValue // First unwrap it
       where newValue.count > 0 else { // Then check if the unwrapped value has items
           return // If not we don't continue
   }

   // From this point you don't need to use ? or ! to access newValue anymore
```

Always try to use safe patterns in your Swift code. To me casting with ! is a code smell and I would always try to replace it with a **if let thing = thing** or **guard let thing = thing** statement

Comment: It's Swift 2.0 new feature and I think ! makes code shorter.

Comment: You mean as long as the first is false :P otherwise we would have a crash

Comment: Xcode 7 has been out for a few weeks already, I assumed you were using the latest version. There is a "Swift way to do things", just like there is a way you should use Python even if it also allows you to do things in a Java like way. Swift is a very type safe language and you're should do things safely whenever you can do so. Last reason is that using guard in such a way tells the reader of your code more about the intent of what you want to do. **guard** is always used to check for some things to be true and some optionals to be available before you continue execution.

Comment: The other major difference is that this answer exits early rather than wrapping the rest of the function in an `if`. That's typically very good for readability, and lets the rest of the code be simpler, clearer, and often even shorter.

Comment: I'm now using guard let where I used to use if let in more than 90% of all cases, very seldom an optional parameter set or not set will really trigger different but also correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is safe. Because first part makes the whole statement true so there is no need to evaluate the second part.

If it is possible to determine the result of the whole condition after its part then rest is not evaluated. This is one of the reasons why conditions shouldn't have any side effects (mutate anything)

For a bit more general [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: According to optimizations, if `newValue == nil` is true, then the whole expression is true. So I think `(newValue!).count == 0` will never run... But if you are right, is there any other way to check the two conditions at the same time?

Comment: sorry, made a change to my answer as I was wrong at the beginning

Comment: It's Okay. You've also given me extra advices.

Comment: At the beginning I wrongly interpreted the example. Parser in my brain failed :) @zhongdian also added a more general reading

Answer (score 1):

That statement is perfectly fine and save.

The correct term for this kind of behavior of programming languages is `short-circuit evaluation`.

The boolean statements are only executed until the statement can possibly still result in both `true` and `false` - as soon as the outcome is determined it finishes.

For `&&` that means that if one statement is `false` the execution stops.
For `||` that means that if one statement is `true` the execution stops.

Comment: Thanks! That looks all languages obey this rule.