# IOS swift how can i check for empty array while getting Json data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, anyobject

I am very new to swift and in my code I get JSON from a certain email, the JSON data is first put into an Array in swift, however if the array is null or there is no Json Data I get this error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1067a5748) to 'NSArray' (0x1067a4c58).

I been trying to fix this by reading other posts such as [Check if optional array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588964/check-if-optional-array-is-empty) but it is not working. The issue comes with this code below

```
session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                   print(error)
            } else {
                do {

                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                    if let musicJob = parsedData["music"] as! [AnyObject]?  {

    for S in musicjob {
                        if let genre = S["genre"] as? String {
                            self.genres.append(genre)
                        }
}
}
```

If the Json is null I get the error on this line right here

```
if let musicJob = parsedData["music"] as! [AnyObject]?
```

The **musicJob** counts the number of objects such as "30 values or 44 values " etc . If there is no Json then it returns nil and it crashes . **Is there anyway that I can catch the value of nil or an empty array so that the app does not crash ?** Again everything works as long as the musicJob array is not empty .

Comment: Think a moment about the meaning to forced unwrap an optional to an optional (`as! [AnyObject]?`). Apart from that an unspecified JSON type in Swift 3 is always `Any` rather than `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let musicJob = parsedData["music"] as? [AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check both `nil` and empty for `Array` like this.

```
if let musicJob = parsedData["music"] as? [Any], !musicJob.isEmpty {
    print(musicJob)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can always use conditional unwrapping.  *Force unwrapping* is usually dangerous (crash) and should be used with great care.

First of all, using `guard` to make sure preconditions are met before doing anything is a good practice.

```
if guard let responseData = data else {
    assertionFailure("response data is nil") // no need for assertionFailure is data is expected to be nil sometimes
    return
}
```

And something similar with the line that crashes:

```
if let musicJob = parsedData["music"] as? [AnyObject] {
    ....
}
```